# SQL: Count first instance of ids on each date listed in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to SQL.

Given a table called "badge" with the following fields:

```
badge.id, badge.createdAt, badge.visitorId
```

and a table "visitor" with the following fields:

```
visitor.id

where badge.visitorId = visitor.id
```

Obviously I'm leaving out some fields for simplicity, here, but how can I get back a list of dates that shows a count of only the first instance of visitorId on that day? I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(badge."visitorId")), 
       date_trunc('day', badge."createdAt") AS day 
FROM badge 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY "day";
```

but that's not filtering out the duplicates.  The desired output would look something like this:

```
count  day
1671   2016-03-13 00:00:00
1646   2016-03-14 00:00:00
1050   2016-03-15 00:00:00
```

Where the count reflects the removed duplicates.  (The table above is the current count and I have confirmed there are several hundred duplicates).

Comment: The fact that you are looking for  "_a count of only the first instance of visitorId on that day_" and don't have the `visitorId` in your desired results, doesn't make sense to me. I just don't understand what you want.

Comment: I want a count of the first time a visitorId shows up in the badges table, for each day.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want `min()` and then subsequent aggregation:

```
select theday, count(*)
from (select min(date_trunc('day', createdAt)) as theday, visitorid
      from badges
      group by vistorid
     ) b
group by theday
order by theday;
```

Another method moves the logic to the `where` clause instead of using two aggregations:

```
select date_trunc('day', b.createdAt), count(*)
from badges b
where b.createdAt = (select min(b2.createdAt) from badges b2 where b2.visitorid = b.visitorid);
```

Note:  this version assumes that `createdAt` is unique for any given visitor.